# Check if Latitude & Longitude exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, floating-point

I would like to check to see the Latitude & Longitude already exist in a database. I have a website where people can enter their physical address and it will be displayed on a map.  I do want to prevent though a physical address from being entered twice.  I figure the best way to do this is to compare the Latitude & Longitude of the address to what is stored in the database.

I am using Google Map API to find the Latitude & Longitude of the address entered by the user. Following Google's recommendation, I am storing (caching) these values as a Float (10,6) value.

The issue that I am experience though seems to rounding the Float value when I try to compare the values of an address entered by a user and what I have stored in the database.

Here is the code that I am using to compare these values:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".urlencode($address);
    $lat_long = get_object_vars(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));
    // pick out what we need (lat,lng)
    $lat = $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lng;
    // Check to see if Property is already in database
    $getlatlng = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `Property` WHERE CAST(lat AS DECIMAL(10,6)) = CAST(%s AS DECIMAL(10,6)) AND CAST(lng AS DECIMAL(10,6)) = CAST(%s AS DECIMAL(10,6))",
        $PDO_DB->quote($lat),
        $PDO_DB->quote($lng));
    $resultlatlng = $PDO_DB->query($getlatlng);
    $rowlatlng = $resultlatlng->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

An example of this would be address:  `601 N Lincoln Rd, Escanaba, MI 49829`

The values stored in the database are:

```
lat = 45.752487
lng = -87.082733
```

The values returned by Google Map API are:

```
lat = 45.7524878
lng = -87.0827338
```

My guess has to do with the values being returned from is being rounded to:

```
lat = 45.752488
lng = -87.082734
```

And this results in the what I have in my database and what Google is returning is not equal. The value stored in the database is stored off the same code as above, just left off the section that is inserting the values into the database.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-cmp.php

Comment: You only store 6 decimal places. `0827338` is 7. `Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.`-http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: Would changing the field the value is stored within MySQL to be FLOAT(11,7) be an good fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Aaron for pointing out the PHP command BCCOMP.  I used it to solve the issue.

Here is the code now:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".urlencode($address);

$lat_long = get_object_vars(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));
// pick out what we need (lat,lng)
$lat = $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lng;

$propertyexist = FALSE; 

    // Check to see if Property is already in database  
    $getlatlng = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `Property`");
    $resultlatlng = $PDO_DB->query($getlatlng);
    $rowlatlng = $resultlatlng->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rowlatlng AS $rowlt) {
        $checklat = bccomp($rowlt['lat'], $lat, 6);
        $checklng = bccomp($rowlt['lng'], $lng , 6);

        if (($checklat === 0) && ($checklng === 0)) {
            $propertyexist = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
```